# MVC hidden fields not posting back

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, postback

I am using an EditorFor on a list of `ComponentParameter`s (shown below).  The editor template switches based on the value, and the datetime isn't working.  When I look at the HTML before postback, the values are there, but in the `List<ComponentParameter>` inside the model, the spots corresponding to the datetimes are null.

```
public class ComponentParameter
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Optional { get; set; }
}
```

EditorTemplate:

```
@switch (Model.Type.ToLowerInvariant())
{
case "datetime":
        Html.RenderPartial("ParameterHeader", Model); 
<div class="grid_4">
    @{
        DateTime value;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(Model.Value, out value))
        {
            value = DateTime.Today + TimeSpan.FromHours(6);
        }
    }
    // Commenting out the next 2 lines causes the value to post back
    <div class="grid_9">@Html.TextBox("", value.ToString("MM/d/yyyy"), new { @class = "date-picker autotooltip " + Model.RequiredClass, @data_mwtooltip = Model.Description })</div>
    @Html.TextBox("", value.ToString("hh:mm tt"), new {@class="time-picker"})
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Value, new { @class = "input-time-picker" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Optional)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Description)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Type)
</div>
        break;
case "string":
    <div class="grid_12">
        @{ Html.RenderPartial("ParameterHeader", @Model); }
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Value, new { @class = "autotooltip " + Model.RequiredClass, @data_mwtooltip = Model.Description })
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Optional)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Description)
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Type)
    </div>
        break;
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="grid_4">
<div class="grid_9">
<span class="ui-spinner ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<input id="ComponentList_0__ComponentParameterList_0_" class="time-picker ui-spinner-input valid" type="text" value="06:00 AM" name="ComponentList[0].ComponentParameterList[0]" aria-valuenow="1357041600000" autocomplete="off" role="spinbutton">
<a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
<a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-down ui-corner-br ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
</span>
<input id="ComponentList_0__ComponentParameterList_0__Value" class="input-time-picker" type="hidden" value="07/11/2013 06:00 AM" name="ComponentList[0].ComponentParameterList[0].Value">
<input id="ComponentList_0__ComponentParameterList_0__Optional" type="hidden" value="False" name="ComponentList[0].ComponentParameterList[0].Optional">
<input id="ComponentList_0__ComponentParameterList_0__Description" type="hidden" value="Start Time" name="ComponentList[0].ComponentParameterList[0].Description">
<input id="ComponentList_0__ComponentParameterList_0__Type" type="hidden" value="datetime" name="ComponentList[0].ComponentParameterList[0].Type">
</div>
<div class="grid_12">
<label>
<input id="ComponentList_0__ComponentParameterList_5__Value" class="autotooltip paramRequired required" type="text" value="" name="ComponentList[0].ComponentParameterList[5].Value" data-mwtooltip="Attention Line" title="">
<input id="ComponentList_0__ComponentParameterList_5__Optional" type="hidden" value="False" name="ComponentList[0].ComponentParameterList[5].Optional">
<input id="ComponentList_0__ComponentParameterList_5__Description" type="hidden" value="Attention Line" name="ComponentList[0].ComponentParameterList[5].Description">
<input id="ComponentList_0__ComponentParameterList_5__Type" type="hidden" value="string" name="ComponentList[0].ComponentParameterList[5].Type">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the case, but the index `[n]` *must* be 0-based *and* sequential in order for model binding to work.

Comment: @Andre: Yes there are 6 elements in the array, the first 2 (0 and 1) are for the non-working datetimes, and the last 4 (which show up in the postback) are for working strings and textareas.  I only posted one example of each.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I feel like there's some code missing. Could you provide your whole view and the signature of the action that's receiving the post?

Comment: @AndreCalil: I'm not sure that would help.  The Models and views are all rather large.  I did discover that commenting out the 2 TextBox items causes the value to be posted back.  I don't understand why that makes a difference, but hopefully that will give insight.

Comment: As far as I could follow your code, I believe that the commented textbox would generate the input named `ComponentList[0].ComponentParameterList[0]`, right? Maybe it's overwriting the other properties, like `.Name` and `.Value`

Comment: @AndreCalil Yes that one was the problem.  I don't know exactly what it was trying to do that caused the element to appear as null, but it wasn't supposed to come back to the model at all.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the HTML again, the issue is that the Html helpers were trying to bind to the model as well, as evidenced by `id="ComponentList_0__ComponentParameterList_0_"`.  This seemed to cause that model to not bind at all, due to the errors.

Since I was only trying to get some input fields to work with, I removed those and replaced them with regular HTML `<input>`.

Comment: I can't see why the `id` could be the problem. But if it solved your problem, way to go.

Comment: That's not a proper solution. The problem is that you are using a nested model. You can still use Html Helpers, but you need to use a proper prefix in your controller action so the binding works. Unfortunately, I can't help you better, because you haven't posted your entire View. At least, I need to know what Model you are passing to your View so I can better assist you.

Comment: @ataravati A proper solution to the model trying to bind things that don't exist, isn't to make it so that the model doesn't try to bind things that don't exist?  Nested models is the problem? We use them everywhere else in our solution.  Why would they provide EditorTemplates if you weren't supposed to use Nested Models?  Perhaps I don't even need an <input> box, we don't need the values from those things, but that's hardly what you're saying.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Of course you can use nested models, but in order for the binding to work, you need to use a Bind attribute in your controller action with a proper Prefix. 

I can't be sure, but it looks like your model is an IEnumerable<ComponentList> and each ComponentList  in your Model has an IEnumerable<ComponentParameterList>. All I'm saying is that using  <input> tags is not a good solution. You can still make this work using Html Helpers. I can help you better if you give me more information about your Model and your View.

Comment: It works exactly how I want it to.  The stuff that I changed away from HTML Helpers are NOT supposed to be bound.